# Java- Declare an object of a type chosen by the user

Tags: java, reflection, polymorphism

I don't know if this is possible, but what I'd like to know is the following:

Let's say I have an array which contains 2 different class type:

```
Fruit[] fruit;
fruit[0]= new Banana();
fruit[1]= new Apple();
```

What I want to do is this:

```
Fruit unknown= new fruit[0].getClass();
```

I want to declare an object of a type which is chosen by the user. Can I do it?

Comment: Research Java "reflection".  If you really need to do dynamic programming (which is what you are implying with your question) then Java may not be the right language.

Comment: It is totally possible and not that hard. Google java reflection

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/36272566/3888450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very hard -- you are most of the way there. There is a method called `newInstance()` on the `Class` interface that you can use like this:

```
Fruit userFruit = (Fruit) Class.forName(input).newInstance();
```

(where `input` is a String containing a class name representing a user's choice) to return a new instance of the type you have.

Comment: I had completely messed up my answer, but it was 'accepted' so I've stolen Adam Rice's answer from below simply to make mine right for future readers. Adam deserves the rep for this, but I don't know how to give it to him.

Comment: Oh, but I actually just needed to know the function newInstance(), since you were the first I accepted yours.

Comment: Yeah, but SO answers are there for future readers too, so should be as correct as possible.

Answer (score 4):

I presume the user will be saying that they want an "Apple" or a "Banana" i.e. you'll get input as a String. In which case this might be what you need.

```
Fruit f = (Fruit) Class.forName("Banana").newInstance();
   fruit[0] = f;
```

Comment: Hey Adam, I stole your answer, sorry. I've made up the rep for you by finding other posts you've made on SO and upvoted good ones.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use reflection, consider using a combination of the Factory and Strategy design patterns. Have the input processing code examine the input to see what kind of thing they want, and hence select a Factory/Strategy object. Then, later, when you need the object created, ask the Factory/Strategy object to create it.